# unable to enter number in output in c++

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int num1,num2,result;
 cout << "enter num 1"<<endl;
 cin >> num1;
 cout << "enter num 2"<<endl;
 cin >> num2;
 result = num1 + num2;
 cout << num1 <<"+" << num2 << " = "<< result;
 return 0
}
```

this is the code I am unable to enter in output for adding the numbers
I wrote c++ code of adding two nums when output is given to enter 1st no then I am unable to write the no how can I write that output

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after `return 0`. Once this is fixed, your program [works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/1vqcn6fPG)

Answer (score 0):

The last sentence your code :"return 0"，didn't write ";".